# How the netbeans debugger (xdebug) can jump back to breakpoint, if breakpoint was already reached?

Tags: php, debugging, drupal, netbeans, xdebug

I have a drupal module with a function which is called more than 1 time. With the »run to cursor« button, I can jump to the breakpoint once.

But after I'm stepping out from the breakpoint, which is inside a function, which will be called more then 1 time, I cannot return with the »run to cursor«-button, to check, what happens at the second call of my function.

Has anybody an idea? Thank's in front.

Answer (score 2):

If you have breakpoint inside your function can't you just `Continue` (F5) debugging? Xdebug will stop on this breakpoint when the function is called.

Comment: Xdebug stops, but after Xdebug has been one the breakpoint once, I cannot step back to the breakpoint again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. XDebug does not allow that. There a couple of commercial solutions. Although maybe if enough votes are put into that feature it'll get done...